# How to get bitcoins for testing?

Tags: testing, bitcoin

I'm trying to test bitcoin and I would like to win 1 bitcoins or even 0.00001 just to see how is it to receive and send money.
I visited many faucets, I filled surveys, I watched ads but I never get my payment in bitcoins !
Do you know a website which really sends a micro sum of bitcoins just for me to test ?

Windows 7 / Firefox 50.0

Comment: I would also like to get free money

Comment: I forgot to say it, but I would like to get bitcoins without using my credit card.

Comment: www.gofundme.com?

Comment: [Testnet?](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/)

Comment: I doubt anyone will send you free bitcoins. However, you can buy small amounts (down to ~5$ of bitcoins) on bitcoin exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see how Bitcoin works use the TestNet, 
here you got explanations and some real faucets links. 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet

Answer (score 0):

Since mainnet bitcoins are rather expensive, testing there is definitely not desirable. Bitcoin provides you with two other options to develop software against: [Regtest mode](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode) and the [Testnet network](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testnet). Testnet is a distributed network that operates exactly like mainnet, with some more advanced features being tested. The coins on testnet are not worth anything on purpose so that software can be tested there with realistic conditions. Since testnet coins aren't worth anything there are [faucets](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/) that will give you some coins.

The other option is regtest mode. This is sometimes called *testnet in a box* and allows you to spin up an isolated network on your own machine. This network is fully under your control, and you can even generate blocks as quickly as you want. Many projects use regtest mode to run automated integration test suites against their software.